# postgresql affinity - docker service to swarm

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, affinity

I am new to docker, and I have a problem. I want to gain affinity and exchanging data between two nodes in docker swarm.

(example ip)

I have one as manager: `192.168.10.1`

and worker on: `192.168.10.2`

They are already connected.

I have wrote `docker-compose.yml` file to create new service with postgres DB, and 
manager yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: My_DB
            POSTGRES_USER: My_DB_User
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: My_DB_Password
            PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdatai
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role == manager
                    - node.labels.type == queue

    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

and worker:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: My_DB
            POSTGRES_USER: My_DB_User
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: My_DB_Password
            PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdatai
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints:
                    - node.role == worker
                    - node.labels.type == queue

    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
```

And I dont have any stack on my machines. Doing command below (not sure if correct one) I have an error: `yaml: line 2: did not find expected key`

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml my_hostname
```

my hostname is read by me from command `docker node ls` in manager machine

Maybe someone has dealed with a very similiar issue and goals and can give me a guidance. I have looked at several demos on internet, but I found those a little bit useless. I would appreciate any help and guides of how I can achieve this "backup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I now understand yaml more. For anyone else, who occures similar problems:

1) check your writing in yml file. You should take double care about white marks.

2) I reconfigured yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
   POSTGRES_DB: db_db
   POSTGRES_USER: db_user
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_pass
   PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdatai
  expose:
   - "5432"
  ports:
   - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/postresql/db/
  deploy:
   placement:
    constraints:
     - node.hostname == vmAPI1
```

3) I used command for putting service to running swarm:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml name_of_your_manager_swarm
```